# Does c++ compiler optimize 0*x?

Tags: c++, optimization

Does c++ compiler optimize 0*x? I mean does it
convert to 0 or it actually does the multiplication?

Thanks

Comment: If you know basic assembly, you can see for yourself. But the answer is usually "yes" if they are integer types.

Comment: different compilers are different

Comment: What is the type of `x`?

Comment: with gcc, it's known to throw tokens on the floor and keep going... thats one of the reason for the clang project.. msvc it doesnt, it'll actually do the math, it wont do trivial token folding.

Comment: @Mysticial What if it is of other numerical type, say double. For me it makes sense just to optimize it to 0, but can there be any exception?

Comment: @Ghasan `0 * INF` is not `0` for floating-point.

Comment: @Mysticial: In IEEE754 math. A number of compilers have aggresive "not-entirely-compliant" optimizations, usually optional.

Answer (score 8):

It might:

```
int x = 3;
int k = 0 * 3;
std::cout << k;

00291000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (29203Ch)] 
00291006  push        0    
00291008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (292038h)]
```

It even optimizes away the variables altogether.

But it might not:

```
struct X
{
    friend void operator *(int first, const X& second)
    {
       std::cout << "HaHa! Fooled the optimizer!";
    }
};

//...
X x;
0 * x;
```

Comment: In addition, for IEEE floating point arithmetic, 0*x is not always 0.

Comment: In your example, `0 * 3` is simplified to `0` due to a "Constant Folding" optimization, and would have happened for any two constants multiplied.  There is a seperate optimization `0 * x` ==> `0` that occurs even if x is a variable, and not constant.

Answer (score 6):

If x is a primitive integral type than the code generator will use optimizations generally referred to as "Arithmetic Rules" to make changes such as:

```
int x = ...;
y = 0 * x;   ===> y = 0
y = 1 * x;   ===> y = x
y = 2 * x;   ===> y = x + x;
```

but only for integral types.

If x is of a non-integral type than `0 * x` might not always be equal to `0`, or may have side-effects.

Comment: but only for primitive types. Do you have a reference on that? I bet it is not true for float.

Comment: Compiler optimizations are not standardized, so there is no reference.  However you are correct it doesn't make it for float because 0 * NaN = NaN, and so on.  I have updated my answer to specifically integral types.

Comment: Compiler optimizations are not in general standard violating, so I think I had a valid remark.

Comment: GCC has a fast-math option that enables further optimizations at the expense of strict IEEE compliance. One of those I believe is to optimize to 0 and thus 0*Nan can actually become zero (the check for NaN is costly, and mostly you don't care, so it makes sense at times).

Comment: Yes, --fast-math turns 0 times nan into 0. But -O3 does not.